# Looking for PyCharm Remote Dev experience similar to VS Code Remote SSH Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Is there anything like that? I'd like to try and maybe switch to PyCharm, but it's impossible for me without an extension like that.

Comment: Could you please briefly describe what "VS Code Remote SSH Extension" does / what functionality you require?

Comment: @LazyOne vscode basically permits to open folders, run debugger, linter, integrated terminal...

Comment: I'm not using PyCharm but another JetBrains IDE .. but it will be almost identical here. 1) The IDE is built around "local code first, remote is just a copy" approach. It needs fast access to your code. 2) IDE needs to index whole project (required files) to provide you with code completion (for functions/classes defined in the project; not a standard library stuff). 3) IDE has built-in SSH terminal, SFTP support.

Comment: 4) Because of #1 and #2 the recommended approach is: make a local copy of the project, work with it and setup Deployment so it can **automatically** copy all files to your desired remote location on Save or on demand (test server etc). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/deploying-applications.html & https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#autoupload_definitions 5) You can browse your remote files via built-in SFTP access: if you click to edit the file, IDE will download it to local location, index and open it.

Comment: 6) At the same time you may use "Remote Edit", when downloaded file is kept temp location/outside of the project so it's not part of the project (*this is PhpStorm help link, but it should work exactly the same if it's available in PyCharm:* https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html)

Comment: 7) If Deployment is not acceptable for whatever reason, you can mount your remote location in your OS (network share or whatever) and then open the project using local mounted path. IDE will complain on latency (see #1 -- needs fast access to check for file modifications/to index them etc). It is not officially recommended or supported by JetBrains .. but for many users this works OK (especially if it's low latency connection/access).

Comment: 8) If you want "full remote, nothing local" -- sorry, this IDE is not made for this (although there is Projector project (https://github.com/JetBrains/projector-docker) -- you install it on your remote server and work with IDE via browser. Some screenshots and how-to/first hand experience from some user -- it's in Russian but you may use Google Translate for this: https://habr.com/ru/post/510210/

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but I recently wanted to do this and got things working. I found [this](https://medium.com/@albert.brand/remote-to-a-vm-over-an-iap-tunnel-with-vscode-f9fb54676153) article which got me most of the way there. Basically you can update your ssh config file yourself with the needed info, just like Remote SSH does for VS Code. The one difference is that PyCharm wants the top level Host value to be something it's checks think is a valid value. So I updated it to something I know will never get used elsewhere, but also is valid.

My end input into my ssh config looks just like in that article, except I replaced the very top Host compute.x value with Host renee.local

Example:

```
Host renee.local
  HostName compute.<instance_id>
  IdentityFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_engine
  CheckHostIP no
  HostKeyAlias compute.<instance_id>
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  StrictHostKeyChecking yes
  UserKnownHostsFile /Users/<user_name>/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
  ProxyCommand /Users/<user_name>/miniconda3/bin/python3 -S /Users/<user_name>/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py beta compute start-iap-tunnel <instance_name> %p --listen-on-stdin --project=<project_name> --zone=us-central1-a --verbosity=warning
  ProxyUseFdpass no
  User <user_name>
```

Comment: Could you put that example SSH config inline instead of an image? That would allow others to use your answer much more easily.

Comment: @BenCox Sure thing! Updated it.